# Why the code that is not included in an item being exported still runs when imported?

Tags: reactjs

```
//Govegan.js
console.log('inside Govegan.js');

export function MyLife(){
//empty funciton
}

//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {Govegan} from './Govegan';

class App extends.React.Component{
render(){
  return(<div>Hello</div>);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
//console output: inside Govegan.js
```

Console.log before MyLife function still runs in index.js even though we just imported an empty MyLife function.

Comment: you can export constants too, therefore node needs to run the code in the whole file in order correctly exports everything, in your case you are exporting a function but as I said, node needs to run everything to find out if there's something else that needs to be exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The described behaviour is expected to happen when your ES6 codes gets transpiled to ES5 and then executed.

> In the current module systems(ES5), the code needs to be executed to find out what is exported and what is imported.

This is the reason your `console.log` gets printed when you import it, as the imported file gets executed.

> In ES6 this is not expected to happen because, the imports and exports are identified at compile time statically and the code does not needs to be executed to resolve the imports and exports.